# Remove encrypted duplicate in javascript array

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a piece of javascript that is collecting all the specified values on a page and pushing them into an array. This array is later joined into a string.

```
 $('.myClass input:checked').each(function () {
myArray.push($(this).next().text());
  });
```

The problem I have discovered is I have some duplicates and if I remove one value I need to remove all the values that match that except the text is encrypted. I'm not sure trying to decrypt in JS is a good idea but I presume its possible. Or I've thought it might be possible to somehow flag this value so I could remove it after decryption in the code behind. What's the best way to get rid of these duplicates?

UPDATE: Sample data

The data is retrieved from a database and stored in a hidden label, encrypted.

The encryption is just standard lbl1.Text = Encryption.Encrypt(myText)

The array is created with the encrypted values.

```
  Id
  ----
  FomEUe9wlfs= 
  tBmdbAwtLqQ=
  lImleQljIjw=
  tBmdbAwtLqQ=
```

At a later point these values are joined into a string and sent server side where they are decrypted and processed.

Comment: How are they encrypted in the first place? Does the same string not encrypt to the same value? What does you data look like? Can you provide an example?

Comment: It might not matter that they are encrypted (depends upon how they are encrypted).  With some encryption, all encrypted duplicates would still be duplicates so you could still remove duplicates even though they were encrypted.

Comment: It's asp.net encryption done in the code behind when the page loads. I double checked, the encrypted values are the same.